# Unity WebGL build error: The name Network does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

I'm trying to build a multiplayer WebGL game with Unity3D, with the new UNET system. It runs perfectly in the editor, and builds perfectly for Mac and Windows, but I try to build it for WebGL it gives me this error in multiple scripts:

> The name Network does not exist in the current context

It runs fine in the editor for WebGL though, the errors show when I try to build. I've been reading this documentation but cannot figure out why it's not showing. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html

I'm on the latest version of Unity, 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network package is not part of the UNET. It's the old Unity networking system, and it's not supported by WebGL builds.

[Source](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/the-name-network-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context.448727/)